# Can a high level warlock with Book of Ancient Secrets learn ritual spells higher than 5th level?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spellcasting, eldritch-invocations, rituals

Let's say I'm an 11th level Pact of the Tome Warlock with Book of Ancient Secrets. I'm able to learn spells to cast as rituals from any source, I can transcribe spells up to half my level rounded up, and have just gotten my 6th level Mystic Arcanum.

I do not actually have 6th level slots, but ritual casting doesn't use spell slots anyway, and I am capable of casting 6th level spells (or at least one). Am I able to transcribe a 6th level ritual spell, or am I capped at learning 5th level rituals?

Comment: Related: [At which levels, if any, can a Warlock use a Spell Scroll of 6th Level or Higher?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165892/48793)

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, but it's not a big deal

There are only two spells that are above 5th level and have the "ritual" tag; [Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance) and [Drawmij's Instant Summons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons)

Let's look at the wording of the [Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures):

> You can now inscribe magical rituals in your Book of Shadows. Choose two 1st-level spells that have the ritual tag from any class’s spell list (the two needn’t be from the same list). The spells appear in the book and don’t count against the number of spells you know. With your Book of Shadows in hand, you can cast the chosen spells as rituals. You can’t cast the spells except as rituals, unless you’ve learned them by some other means. You can also cast a warlock spell you know as a ritual if it has the ritual tag.
>
> On your adventures, you can add other ritual spells to your Book of Shadows. When you find such a spell, you can add it to the book **if the spell’s level is equal to or less than half your warlock level (rounded up)** and if you can spare the time to transcribe the spell. For each level of the spell, the transcription process takes 2 hours and costs 50 gp for the rare inks needed to inscribe it.

So you start with two spells from any class list, so long as they are rituals. As you adventure, you can also transcribe other ritual spells, so long as their level is half of your **warlock level**, rounded down. Not the level of spell you can cast. So at 12th level, you can cast 6th level ritual spells, so long as you have acquired and transcribed them into your Book of Shadows.

Additional, you can "cast a warlock spell you know as a ritual if it has the ritual tag." But once again, this list is very limited; seven total if we include all Warlock sub-classes:

- Comprehend Languages
- Illusory Script
- Unseen Servant
- Silence
- Feign Death
- Meld into Stone
- Contact other Plane

### And it works for Arcanum, too

If some future rule change adds either Forbiddance or Instant Summons as an Arcanum, or they make a new sub-class with a new 6th-level ritual spell, those work too.

The wording of Arcanum states:

> At 11th level, your patron bestows upon you a magical secret called an arcanum. Choose one 6th-level spell from the warlock spell list as this arcanum.
>
> You can cast your arcanum spell once without expending a spell slot. You must finish a long rest before you can do so again.
>
> At higher levels, you gain more **warlock spells** of your choice that can be cast in this way.

So Arcanum are warlock spells, and the Invocation states that the character can cast ritual warlock spells as rituals.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the feature allows you to cast non-warlock spells as rituals. It takes the time to explicitly state you can cast warlock spells that have the ritual tag, why would it do that if you could cast any spell that has the ritual tag?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov "Choose two 1st-level spells that have the ritual tag from any class’s spell list (the two needn’t be from the same list) [...] **With your Book of Shadows in hand, you can cast the chosen spells as rituals.** You can’t cast the spells except as rituals, unless you’ve learned them by some other means. You can also cast a warlock spell you know as a ritual if it has the ritual tag." It lets *Book of Shadows* replace the *Ritual Caster* feat for Warlock spells, and also lets you acquire rituals from other classes.

Comment: The whole first paragraph is talking about ritual spells from any class with only the last sentence explaining that warlock spells can be cast also. The second paragraph says, "...you can add other ritual spells to your Book of Shadows". Not warlock ritual spells, just ritual spells. Nothing states that the spells you enter need to be warlock only, in fact it goes out of the way to say that the spells can be from any class. It calls out the warlock spells as a bonus--Those few spells that are ritual no longer use your precious spell slots if cast as a ritual.

Comment: @Upper_Case "With your Book of Shadows in hand, you can cast the **chosen** spells as rituals." It lets you cast the two chosen spells as rituals. *It does not say you can cast non-warlock ritual spells you find later as rituals*.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It's the feature that describes you can cast non-Warlock rituals spells as rituals, as requested in your first comment under this answer. Whether or not that applied to rituals added later is separate to that, though perhaps what you had meant in asking.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, what would be the point of adding ritual spells to your Shadow book if you cannot cast them? Or are you saying that the character can only add the 7 or less warlock spells that are also ritual to the book?

Comment: What would be the point of stating you can cast warlock spells with the ritual tag if you can already cast any spell with the ritual tag?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Perhaps to indicate that you don't need to spend the time and gold to inscribe them in the book. Taking the invocation grants the ability to cast your Warlock spells as rituals immediately, in addition to your two free 1st-level ritual spells from other classes.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, because without this invocation, warlocks can't cast as ritual. So it's a bonus; not only can you cast other classes rituals, but if you know a warlock spell that has the ritual tag, you can now cast them as a ritual too! This give the player the chance to cast the warlock ritual spells either as a ritual, OR as a normal pact spell.